# Cannot find procedure or trigger listed in message sql server

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, triggers

Using SQL Server 2014  , yesterday my Entity Framework code updated a table just fine.  Today from Visual studio i was confused at why it was telling me

`String or binary data would be truncated.`

Then I tried to update within SSMS

**Message**

`Msg 8152, Level 16, State 14, Procedure tr_rpm_scrty_rpm_usr_aud, Line 70
String or binary data would be truncated.
The statement has been terminated.`

So I figure even though it says "Procedure"  i assume `tr_rpm_scrty_rpm_usr_aud` is a **Trigger**

Either way, how do I find it?   I was looking at properties of the table, since I looked under all sorts of folders and did not see it...

Comment: Global -  look under  Programmability - Database Triggers   ( DDL Triggers)

Table Triggers - are under Tables   ( DML Triggers )

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Server Management Studio table triggers can be found under when you expand a particular table

[image]

Comment: That is DB Triggers   DDL ,  he will need DML Trigger for Tables which are under Tables

Comment: @TomStickel Yep, been a while since I dealt with triggers and completely ran though that to fast, updated answer.

Comment: No problem , good picture addition       (I recall that sql server 2000 didn't even have a folder for triggers at all if i recall correctly,   you had to look at each table.... but i'm sure there were sys and other commands to find all triggers etc.. )     later